# Trouble With Executing Stored Procedure for Each CheckBoxList Item Checked

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures

I am creating a web page using Visual Basic 2012 and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 that will allow the user to enter student dues incurred by multiple students. (ie: 50 new pledges incur $50.00 pledge dues for Fall Semester 2014)

The table being populated is as follows:

```
+----------------+--------------+
| Dues_ID        | int (pk)     |
| Enrollment ID  | int          |
| Type           |  varchar(50) |
| Dues_owed      | int          |
| Description    | varchar(MAX) |
+----------------+--------------+
```

my pk auto-increments. The user enters the enrollment_id by selecting a either fall or spring from a drop down list, and a year also from a drop down list. Once those are selected a checkbox list is generated listing what students are registered in that term and year. Stored Procedure is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SelectStudDueIncrCklst
@Term varchar(50),
@Year int


AS

SELECT S.First_name + ' ' + S.Last_name AS Name, E.Enrollment_ID
FROM Student S
INNER JOIN Student_Enrollment E
ON S.Student_ID = E.Student_ID
WHERE 
(E.Term = @Term)
 AND
(E.Year = @Year)
```

I am trying to allow the user to select multiple students and enter the same due information, however only the first one selected is being ran through the Insert stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.InsertStudDues
@Enrollment_ID int,
@Type varchar(50),
@Dues_owed int,
@Description varchar(MAX)

AS 
DECLARE
@pkStudDues int
set @pkStudDues = 0

SELECT
@pkStudDues=Dues_ID
FROM 
Student_Dues
WHERE
 (Enrollment_ID = @Enrollment_ID)
AND
 (Type = @Type)


IF @pkStudDues = 0

BEGIN
INSERT INTO dbo.[Student_Dues]
    ([Enrollment_ID]
    ,[Type]
    ,[Dues_owed]
    ,[Description])
VALUES
    (@Enrollment_ID
    ,@Type
    ,@Dues_owed
    ,@Description)

    END
```

My code behind (c#):

```
protected void AddDuesbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem c in StdDueNmcklist.Items)
    {
        if (!c.Selected) continue;

            InsertStudDuesdatcon.Insert();
            AddDuesbtn.Visible = false;
            CnfrmStudDueAddlbl.Visible = true;
            CnfrmStudDueAddbtn.Visible = true;



     }

}
```

Like I said, however, it only inserts for the first checkbox list selected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that the loop would restart and return to the first check box. Since this item was already entered, the stored procedure would close.

```
protected void AddDuesbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   for (int i = 0; i < StdDueNmcklist.Items.Count; i++)
   {
       if (StdDueNmcklist.Items[i].Selected)
       {


           InsertStudDuesdatcon.Insert();
           AddDuesbtn.Visible = false;
           CnfrmStudDueAddlbl.Visible = true;
           CnfrmStudDueAddbtn.Visible = true;
           StdDueNmcklist.Items[i].Selected = false;

       }


     }
```